# Find the sum of an infinite series for the following series

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4^{n+1}}$$

Can someone help me find the sum of the series?
I keep getting the sum to be  $ {\frac{1}{12}}$ but the answer is $ {\frac{1}{9}}$.

Very detailed explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the case $x=1/4$ of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n+1}$.

Comment: Isn't just $\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{2}{4^3}+\dfrac{3}{4^4}=\dfrac{27}{256}>\dfrac{1}{12}$?

Comment: how did you find $1/12$?

Comment: Possible dulplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn

Answer (score 0):

Remember that

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n
$$

Take the derivative w.r.t $x$

$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n x^{n-1}
$$

Now use $x = 1/4$

$$
\frac{1}{(1 - 1/4)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{4^{n-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{4^{n-1}}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ for $|x|<1$. So for us, the series is:
$$\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{4^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{16}\frac{d}{dx}\left.\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)\right\vert_{x=1/4}=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{1}{(1-1/4)^2}\right)$$